# Changing from display: none; to :block; with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make this code: `document.getElementById("end_screen").style.display = block;` change the css value for a div with some content from display: none; to display: block;

But when the snippet is run it gives me an error saying it "cannot read the properties of null (Reading 'style')". And i don't know whats wrong please help :)

Comment: What does your HTML look like? It sounds like it hasn't found the element, do you have a typo in the ID somewhere? Also 'block' needs to be in quotes - it's a string.

Comment: also you forget to enclosed display property value block with comma. document.getElementById("end_screen").style.display = 'block'

Comment: @ahmedmoeed That won't work, they can't even get a reference to the HTML element. Also, you forgot to make `"block"` a string 

Comment: @RuanMendes i know the reason for error, also display will be string

Comment: block could be also be a variable, either way that's not the point of the issue, it could as well have been a small typo when asking this question, the real issue is finding DOM element

Comment: @Endless also this happens when we used script into header and finding DOM before loading.

Comment: for references i did not think this answer had to be closed with a more debugging details, it's almost clear what the issue really is. ofc it would help more if html where added,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that it can't find a DOM element on your page that have the id `end_screen`

somewhere in your html you are missing `id="end_screen"`

example `<p id="end_screen" ...>`

Or it could be b/c you are running the code before the DOM have render. in that case move the script to the bottom as the last child or use `document.onload` or something to wait for the DOM rendering to be completed

---

btw, i would instead hide it using `elm.hidden = true` instead of using css to change it. that way you can preserve whatever display value it has. you can also hide a element using the `hidden` attribute `<p hidden>`